# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

> Failed to load http://192.168.1.141:8081/industry: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://192.168.1.140' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

Here is the code

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://192.168.1.141:8081/industry",
    type: "post",
    async: false,
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'text',
    data: {
        'id':id
    },
    success: function(data) {
        datas = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        $("#Industrytype").html("");
        for (var i = 0; i < datas.data.length; i++) {
            $("#Industrytype").append('<option value="'+ datas.data[i].id +'">'+ datas.data[i].name +'</option>');

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: From what have you created the api "http://192.168.1.141:8081/industry" ? 
This seems like the origin of api isn't giving you the permission to access

Comment: You need to enable [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) in your backend api.

Answer (score 1):

Either host your JS code in the same domain+port as the API (in your case 192.168.1.141:8081). Or if you are expecting to make cross domain calls, you need to configure CORS headers from the your server.

Wiki on CORS has some examples on how to do this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing#Simple_example